# Xls export dispays large numbers as decimals

Tags: excel

I am exporting a report in Excel format, however, for customer identifiers that are more than 12 digits, the Excel displays them as decimals e.g. 9876520220007 is displayed as 9.88E+12 or as 9.876520220007. This makes it very hard to verify data because the customer identifier is used to check if the records are correct. Any recommendations or links on how I can display the full number will be appreciated. Thanks!

My data:
[image: Excel doc]

Link to sheet: [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19cn-4SkhvrDUz4WcciHlzoqOkjpKgGzcBL0KHkCXDyY/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Are you using Google Sheets or is it just because of the way you are sharing the file? If you are using Google Sheets you can copy the existing column and paste values into the next column and they are converted to the correct display, then set the format by selecting the column and going to Format > Number > Plain Text. That seems to retain the values correctly on export.

Comment: Im not using google sheets, i uploaded the exel file there so that i could share it. Thats the format of the file that is exported

Answer (score 2):

How are you getting the data into excel? Is it via a csv?

In which case you can use the get data from file option which lets you specify the column type as text before excel messes with it.

You can also set the column format to text. This doesn't fix the ones that excel has already interpreted as a long number but any new ones you paste or type in will stay as text.

You can also put an apostrophe before the text in the cell which forces it to be text.

Thats the only one I can suggest up to now as I don't know how you are getting the data into excel.

Comment: I am getting the data in exel

Answer (score 1):

Select the column and right-click to format cell, and set the decimal place to 0 that should do the trick. but I see you have different types of data in the column you might need to update it individually depending on the case

but I see the

[image]

Comment: Thanks @rohit-pratap This works perfectly for csv but not for exel, the decimal is retained

Comment: @shiro can you share this data as text instead of image

Comment: Added it to the question